# how to create comma separated string in single quotes from arraylist of string in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have requirement in Java to fire a query on MS SQL like

```
select * from customer 
where customer.name in ('abc', 'xyz', ...,'pqr');
```

But I have this IN clause values in the form of ArrayList of String. For ex: the list look like {"abc","xyz",...,"pqr"}

I created a Prepared Statement :

```
 PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(select * from customer 
    where customer.name in (?));
String list= StringUtils.join(namesList, ",");
pStmt.setString(1,list);
rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
```

But the **list** is like **"abc,xyz,..,pqr"**, but I want it as **"'abc','xyz',..,'pqr'"**
so that I can pass it to Prepares Statement.

How to do it in JAva with out GUAVA helper libraries.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I can't check it, but what about `String list= StringUtils.join(namesList, "','");`?

Answer (score 23):

I know this is a really old post but just in case someone is looking for how you could do this in a Java 8 way:

```
private String join(List<String> namesList) {
    return String.join(",", namesList
            .stream()
            .map(name -> ("'" + name + "'"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```
List<String> nameList = ...    
String result = nameList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Comment: I think this is the best and the shortest answer in you are familiar with Java 8 streams

Answer (score 8):

For converting the string you can try this:

```
String list= StringUtils.join(namesList, "','");
list = "'" + list + "'";
```

But i dont thing it's a good idea to pass one string for multiple params.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you formatted the String as you wish, it won't work. You can't replace one placeholder in the `PreparedStatement` with multiple values.

You should build the `PreparedStatement` dynamically to have as many placeholders as there are elements in your input list.

I'd do something like this :

```
StringBuilder scmd = new StringBuilder ();
scmd.append ("select * from customer where customer.name in ( ");
for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++) {
  if (i > 0)
    scmd.append (',');
  scmd.append ('?');
}
scmd.append (")");
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(scmd.toString());

if (namesList.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++) {
        stmt.setString (i + 1, namesList.get(i));
    }
}
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple separator for this type of activity. Essentially you want an object that evaluates to "" the first time around but changes after the first request to return a defined string.

```
public class SimpleSeparator<T> {
  private final String sepString;
  boolean first = true;

  public SimpleSeparator(final String sep) {
    this.sepString = sep;
  }

  public String sep() {
    // Return empty string first and then the separator on every subsequent invocation.
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      return "";
    }
    return sepString;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleSeparator sep = new SimpleSeparator("','");
    System.out.print("[");
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      System.out.print(sep.sep()+i);
    }
    System.out.print("]");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it as following with stream. Almost the same, but a bit shorter.

```
 nameList = List.of("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
                .stream()
                .map(name -> "'" + name + "'")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way to do it is using expression language like that:

```
 String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
 String result = ("" + Arrays.asList(strings)).replaceAll("(^.|.$)", "\'").replace(", ", "\',\'" );
```