# Jdbc template named parameters for querying with IN clause

Tags: java, postgresql

I need to copy the records of one table to another table based on some condition.

```
String query = "insert into public.ticket_booking_archive select * from public.ticket_booking where ticketId in (:ticketIds)";
```

So here the **:ticketIds** are dynamic, where i need to pass ticketIds to make sure whether it satisfies the condition. So it may be the matching and non matching ticket id's here at runtime.

The values of **ticketIds** are something like this
`('f1fa3a42-5837-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002','516fd14d-3c9d-4b4b-91a0-b684d8592dfe','c9652f86-734c-4df5-8ef9-d407cb3eaf7a','df7f2812-b445-45b4-b731-da23c36d7738','f1fa3a42-5837-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002')`. And this is just an example. And the list might goes on.

Since it is of type UUID, I'm storing it into a `Set<UUID>`

```
Set<UUID> tktIds = new HashSet<UUID>();

for(int i=0 ; i<ticketIds.size(); i++) {
String ticketId = ticketIds[i];
tktIds.add(UUID.fromString(ticketId));
}

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("ticketIds", tktIds);

SqlParameterSource namedParameters =
                 new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("ticketIds",params.get("ticketIds"));
```

Since I'm using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, so I'm using like below

```
int res = writeNamedJdbcTemplate.update(query, namedParameters);
```

`res = 3` when executed programmatically.

**Here the problem is, as soon as it finds the first matching value in the IN clause it executes. And it is not considering the other matching values (ticketIds here)**

But if I execute the same query in pgadmin it works fine

```
insert into public.ticket_booking_archive select * from public.ticket_booking where ticketId in ('f1fa3a42-5837-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002','516fd14d-3c9d-4b4b-91a0-b684d8592dfe','c9652f86-734c-4df5-8ef9-d407cb3eaf7a','df7f2812-b445-45b4-b731-da23c36d7738','f1fa3a42-5837-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002');
```

`result is 6.` Working as expected.

`writeNamedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, namedParameters, Integer.class);` //. throws an error

Can anyone please assist? I'm really not sure where I'm making a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether you are using the appropriate JDBC template for the named parameters, but you can do the following:

1. you can consult [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list#NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) to use the right template and employ proper SQL query composition,
2. for string passing you can wrap the parameter mapping as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434931)

after all your named parameter should work